# Populate parent field based on child values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wanting to create a computed column on a parent table that will contain an ID based on the child rows of the parent.

Example Parent Table:

```
ID  Name                CalculatedClassification
1   Parent Item #1      (computed, should return 1)
2   Parent Item #2      (computed, should return 2)
3   Parent Item #3      (computed, should return -1 as there is a mixed result)
```

Example Child Table

```
    ID  Name              ParentRow        ClassificationID
    1   Child Item #1     1                1
    2   Child Item #2     1                1
    3   Child Item #3     1                1
    4   Child Item #4     2                2
    5   Child Item #5     2                2
    6   Child Item #6     3                1
    7   Child Item #7     3                0
    8   Child Item #8     3                1
```

There is a many to many table joining the two but I have left that out for simplicity. Also, the ClassificationID is a foreign key to a classification id table that can grow over time.

Any ideas on how I can do this in a function or other SQL server construct?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend creating a `computed column` when referencing other tables.

There are a couple of ways to do this though.  One is to use the `min` and `max` aggregates with a `case` statement to determine the value:

```
select p.id, 
       p.name, 
       case 
            when min(c.classificationid) = max(c.classificationid) 
            then max(c.classificationid) 
            else -1
        end CalculatedClassification
from parent p 
    join child c on p.id = c.parentrow
group by p.id, p.name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42348/1)

Comment: Perfect, I just tested it in my actual database and it works like a champ. Thank you very much!!!!! Also, I am re-thinking the computed column and perhaps using views to bring everything together.